# Nginx forward proxy based on header value

Tags: nginx

I want to use nginx as forward proxy, but rewrite (also the host part) the URL based on a header value.
Suppose the browser connect to nginx on port 8888 with a regular http request. The header ha the pair:

```
X-myattribute: https://somehost.com
```

nginx should proxy_pass to https://somehost.com

My nginx.conf is now:

```
server {
    listen       8888;
    proxy_connect;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://$http_myattribute;
#            proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
}
```

but I get:

```
2018/08/16 19:44:08 [error] 9#0: *1 invalid port in upstream "https://somehost.com:443", client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8888"
2018/08/16 19:47:25 [error] 9#0: *1 invalid URL prefix in "https://somehost.com:443", client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8888"
```

(two lines depending if I set

```
proxy_pass http://$X-myattribute
```

or

```
proxy_pass https://$X-myattribute
```

or

```
proxy_pass $X-myattribute
```

. Assume X-myattribute always have http:// or https://)

Any suggestion?